# How to stop state from returning initial state after every useEffect call?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In my customHook, I have an onchange event handler that sets the `values` state of a selected item in a drop-down menu. Then based on the state of `values`, I want to fetch some data after every few seconds in my useEffect. However, after every useEffect call, the initial value of the `values` state is called instead of the current state.

I have tried using useRef as in the code to pull the current value but it still returns the initial value.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: "",
        myid: "my-id"
    });

const valuesRef = useRef(values)

const [waitState, setWait] = useState(0) 

//state changers
function handleChange(event, id) {
    setValues({
          ...values,
          name: event.target.value,
          myid: id.props.id,
    });
}

useEffect(() => {         
    valuesRef.current = values

    // logs twice, the first log returns the current state, which I want, 
    // the second logs the initial state, which is useless to me
    console.log(values) 

    let wait = () => {
        setTimeout(() => setWait(waitState+1), 10000)
    }

    async function fetchData() {
        wait()
        //fetch some data
    }

    fetchData()
    }, [waitState, values])}
```

I just expect it to return the current value of `values` state

Comment: Are you missing `}` in `fetchData` ?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question

Comment: Where are you calling `fetchData` ?

Comment: immediately after the declaration. Edited it now